# Bounding the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

For a given $n \times n$-matrix $A$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^n+a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1\lambda+a_0$. I am curious to know if we can upper bound the coefficients of this polynomial using the singular values of A. This is obviously possible when A is symmetric, due to the relation $|\lambda_i| = \sigma_i$.

When A is not symmetric, this is still possible for $|a_0| = |\text{det}(A)| = |\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i| \leq \prod_{i=1}^n \sigma_i$, as well as for $|a_{n-1}| = |\text{trace}(A)| = |\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i$. The second inequality can be found in Theorem 2.4 of [this document](http://www.math.wm.edu/~ckli/ima/note-1.pdf). What about the other coeffients? I am particularly interested in 
$a_{n-2} = \sum_{i<j}\lambda_i\lambda_j$.

**Update:** It would be very interesting if it holds that $|a_{n-2}| \leq \sum_{i<j}\sigma_i\sigma_j$. I am testing this conjecture with random matrices and so far I haven't found a counterexample.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** The above conjecture is now proved in this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323617/an-inequality-on-elementary-symmetric-polynomial-of-eigenvalues/324302#324302).

Comment: +1, any comment on the application?

Comment: Your conjecture appears to be true; see [theorem 4](https://www.ams.org/proc/1954-005-01/S0002-9939-1954-0061573-6/S0002-9939-1954-0061573-6.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @zimbra314. I am assuming you are referring to part (b) of this theorem? But I don't see how $y_{i_1}...y_{i_k} \leq x_1 ... x_k$ can be used to prove the conjecture. It will be useful if $y_{i_1}...y_{i_k} \leq x_{i_1}...x_{i_k}$ but this is not the case.

Comment: @dineshdileep I am working on an optimization problem on the [Steifel manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold). The inequality on $|a_{n-2}|$ shows up in the convergence proof of a proposed algorithm. If you are interested, I can update the main post with more detail on this, but I'm not sure if this is relevant for the main question.

Comment: That's correct. I saw that. You can still use the Part-B to get an upper bound on the product of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should be able to obtain bounds via the Gershgorin circle theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem, or Horn and Johnson's book for a more detailed analysis).

For $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \lambda_i \lambda_j$, we can obtain a more explicit expression by noticing that $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_i \lambda_j=\big(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\big)\big(\sum_{i=j}^n \lambda_j\big)=tr(A)^2$, and therefore $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j<i}\lambda_i \lambda_j =\frac{1}{2}tr(A)^2-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2$. But $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$, so we can simplify this to:
\begin{align*}
a_{n-2}=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\lambda_i \lambda_j=\frac{1}{2}tr(A)^2-tr(A^2).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for $a_{n-2} = \sum_{i<j}\lambda_i\lambda_j$:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i<j}\lambda_i\lambda_j \leq &\sum_{i<j} (\lambda_{i}^{2}+\lambda_{j}^{2})/2\\
= & \frac{n-1}{2}\sum_{i} \lambda_{i}^{2}\\
\leq & \frac{n-1}{2}\sum_{i} \sigma_{i}^{2}\\
\end{align}
$$

This can be extended for $a_{n-3}=\sum_{i<j<k}\lambda_i\lambda_j\lambda_k$
as $\sum_{i<j<k}\lambda_i\lambda_j\lambda_k \leq \sum_{i<j<k}(\lambda_i^{3}+\lambda_j^{3}+\lambda_k^{3})/3 = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{6}\sum_{i}\lambda_i^{3} \leq \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{6}\sum_{i}\sigma_i^{3}  $

Comment: Thanks @zimbra314. Can you explain why $\sum_i \lambda_i^2 \leq \sum_i \sigma_i^2$? Because A is not symmetric, I don't see clearly why this is true.

Comment: perform the Schur decomposition of the matrix and calculate the sum of squares of singular value in terms of eigenvalues; you will get that. I think it will hold for higher exponents as well.